# Replace the " character with a space

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a CSV file, where each comma delimited field is enclosed in `"` - eg. "fred", "bert", "blah". I am trying to use the replace function but can't seem to have it recognize the `"` character. example, if the record is in a string called `buffer`:

```
buffer.replace('\"','')
```

Comment: You don't need to escape the `"` inside `'`s. Your code should work, are you assigning the result back to a variable?

Comment: Try checking whether it truly is a double quote ("), or 2 single quote (')

Comment: Most likely, the quotes are there for a reason; simply replacing them might work now but could lead to problems. For example, how about a line that reads `"foo","bar,baz","bam"`? You should use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to handle CSV files - the option `csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL` will, upon writing, remove all quotes that are not strictly necessary.

Comment: Many thanks.. I will have a look at the csv module.

Answer (score 1):

Add space between double quotes

p = '"fred", "bert", "blah"'

p.replace('\"'," ")

' fred ,  bert ,  blah '

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I've tried with an without a space between the double quotes. Doesnt seem to work. I'll keep trying options...

Comment: try with space it will work   p.replace('\"',"<space>")                                                    just copy paste the above line

Answer (score 0):

Why do you escape the double quotes if it's inside single quotes ?

Try the following :

```
a = '"my string"'
a = a.replace('"',' ')
print(a)
#=> ' my string '
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not replacing it with `space` firstly, but with empty string

Try using  `buffer.strip("\"")`

Comment: Thank you. It didnt work. I'll keep exploring options.